# Make: `test' не требует обновления

Tags: makefile, c++

Есть Makefile

```
PROJECT = test

SOURCES = main.cpp test.cpp
OBJECTS = $(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)
INC = -I./test_lib

LDFLAGS = -L./test_lib
LIBS = -ltest
RM = rm -f

test:
    g++ -c $(INC) $(SOURCES)
    g++ $(LDFLAGS) -o $(PROJECT) $(OBJECTS) $(LIBS)
    $(RM) *.d *.o

clean:
    $(RM) *.d *.o

.PHONY: clean
```

Делаю make, создается файл test. Вношу изменения в main.cpp или test.cpp, делаю make, получаю сообщение "make: `test' не требует обновления."

Как это исправить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Написать, что test зависит от SOURCES

```
test: $(SOURCES)
```

а лучше

```
$(PROJECT): $(SOURCES)
```

а сейчас он у Вас ни то чего не зависит. Т.е. если файла test нет, то выполнятся команды

```
g++ -c $(INC) $(SOURCES)
g++ $(LDFLAGS) -o $(PROJECT) $(OBJECTS) $(LIBS)
$(RM) *.d *.o
```

а если он уже есть, то делать ничего не надо (так у Вас сейчас Makefile написан).

--

Советую изменить имя test на что-нибудь другое (tst, my-test, ...), поскольку есть системная команда test и если Вы пропишете в PATH '.', то сильно удивитесь результатам вызова.

Comment: точку прописывает только винда. И то, в последних версиях вроде поумнела и ругается.

А на линуксе прописать точку в PATH - так это ССЗБ.

Comment: @KoVadim, неужели сейчас уже никому не лень каждый раз пару символов `./` набирать? 


Когда-то это было весьма распространено.

Comment: абсолютно не лень. К тому же набирать часто не нужно. А вот дыру в безопасности делает огромную. Представьте себе, что обычный sudo добавят в домашний каталог.

Comment: И что такого страшного случиться?

Comment: и запускаете sudo, что бы выполнить какую то задачу от имени рута, а она Ваш пароль записала, а машину в ддос станцию превратила. А так - ничего страшного. Пример с sudo конечно надуманный, но есть руткиты, которые половину системы "обновить" могут.

А то, что конкретно Ваша машина никому не нужна - да, это так. Но если таких собрать несколько тысяч - то это уже мощный инструмент.

Comment: А, Вы про подставы. 

Мне больше нравится старая, для алфавитно-цифровых терминалов, имитирующая login.